java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @69d7d0b0
I am trying to deploy my application on open liberty jakartaee10-24.0.0.11. I get the following error:
com.ibm.ws.container.service.state.StateChangeException: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.WeldException: WELD-001524: Unable to load proxy class for bean Built-in Bean [jakarta.transaction.UserTransaction] with qualifiers [@Default] with class interface jakarta.transaction.UserTransaction

Looking at ffdc logs, it seems this error message is a consequence of :
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @69d7d0b0

I am running openjdk 17.
Could you please help me understand and get rid of that error?
Below is my server.xml. It is still work in progress, especially the datasource and authentication parts.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<server description="new server">

    <mpHealth-2.2 livenessCheckEnabled="true"/>

    <httpEndpoint id="defaultHttpEndpoint"
                  httpPort="9080"
                  httpsPort="9443" />

    <applicationManager autoExpand="true"/>
    <library id="postgresqlLib">
        <file name="C:\path/to\postgresql-42.5.1.jar"/>
    </library>
    <featureManager>
        <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
        <feature>beanValidation-3.0</feature>
        <feature>servlet-6.0</feature>
        <feature>appSecurity-5.0</feature>
        <feature>ssl-1.0</feature>
        <feature>restConnector-2.0</feature>
        <feature>jdbc-4.3</feature>
        <feature>enterpriseBeansLite-4.0</feature>
        <feature>concurrent-3.0</feature>
        <feature>persistence-3.1</feature>
        <feature>cdi-4.0</feature>
        <feature>jndi-1.0</feature>
        <feature>jakartaee-10.0</feature>
    </featureManager>

    <jdbc-connection-pool name="PostgresPool" res-type="javax.sql.DataSource" datasource-classname="org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource">
        <property name="serverName" value="xxx"/>
        <property name="portNumber" value="xxx"/>
        <property name="databaseName" value="xxx"/>
        <property name="User" value="xxx"/>
        <property name="Password" value="xxx"/>
        <property name="URL" value="jdbc:postgresql://xxx"/>
    </jdbc-connection-pool>
    <jdbc-resource pool-name="PostgresPool" jndi-name="xxx"/>
        
    <dataSource id="xxx" jndiName="jdbc/xxx">
        <jdbcDriver libraryRef="postgresqlLib"/>
        <properties databaseName="xxx"
                    serverName="xxx"
                    portNumber="xxx"
                    user="xxx"
                    password="xxx"
                    currentSchema="xxx"/>
    </dataSource>

    <jpa persistenceUnitName="xxx" dataSource="xxx"/>

    <applicationManager autoExpand="true"/>
    <dropins>
        <application location="xxx" />
    </dropins>

    <logging traceSpecification="*=audit=enabled"/>
    <audit>
        <auditRecordFactory>
            <jsonAuditData />
        </auditRecordFactory>
        <auditFile>
            <file name="${server.output.dir}/logs/audit.log" />
        </auditFile>
    </audit>

    <administrator-role>
        <user>admin</user>
    </administrator-role>

    <basicRegistry id="basic" realm="BasicRealm">
       <user name="admin" password="xxx" />
    </basicRegistry>

    <application-bnd>
          <security-role name="xxx">
               <user name="admin"/>
           </security-role>
     </application-bnd>

</server>

Below is the part of the ffdc log file that seems relevant:
------Start of DE processing------ = [26/11/2024 14:43:31:797 CET]
Exception = com.ibm.ws.container.service.state.StateChangeException
Source = com.ibm.ws.app.manager.module.internal.SimpleDeployedAppInfoBase
probeid = 624
Stack Dump = com.ibm.ws.container.service.state.StateChangeException: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.WeldException: WELD-001524: Unable to load proxy class for bean Built-in Bean [jakarta.transaction.UserTransaction] with qualifiers [@Default] with class interface jakarta.transaction.UserTransaction
    at com.ibm.ws.container.service.state.internal.ApplicationStateManager.fireStarting(ApplicationStateManager.java:57)
    at com.ibm.ws.container.service.state.internal.StateChangeServiceImpl.fireApplicationStarting(StateChangeServiceImpl.java:52)
    at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.module.internal.SimpleDeployedAppInfoBase.preDeployApp(SimpleDeployedAppInfoBase.java:623)
    at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.module.internal.SimpleDeployedAppInfoBase.installApp(SimpleDeployedAppInfoBase.java:584)
    at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.module.internal.DeployedAppInfoBase.deployApp(DeployedAppInfoBase.java:625)
    at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.war.internal.WARApplicationHandlerImpl.install(WARApplicationHandlerImpl.java:67)
    at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.internal.statemachine.StartAction.execute(StartAction.java:199)
    at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.internal.statemachine.ApplicationStateMachineImpl.enterState(ApplicationStateMachineImpl.java:1369)
    at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.internal.statemachine.ApplicationStateMachineImpl.run(ApplicationStateMachineImpl.java:912)
    at com.ibm.ws.threading.internal.ExecutorServiceImpl$RunnableWrapper.run(ExecutorServiceImpl.java:298)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.WeldException: WELD-001524: Unable to load proxy class for bean Built-in Bean [jakarta.transaction.UserTransaction] with qualifiers [@Default] with class interface jakarta.transaction.UserTransaction
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyFactory.getProxyClass(ProxyFactory.java:409)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyFactory.run(ProxyFactory.java:360)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyFactory.create(ProxyFactory.java:352)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.builtin.ee.AbstractEEBean.<init>(AbstractEEBean.java:36)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.jta.UserTransactionBean.<init>(UserTransactionBean.java:52)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.jta.WeldTransactionsModule.preBeanRegistration(WeldTransactionsModule.java:46)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.WeldModules.preBeanRegistration(WeldModules.java:158)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployment.createBeans(BeanDeployment.java:224)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.deployBeans(WeldStartup.java:435)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.deployBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:87)
    at com.ibm.ws.cdi.impl.CDIContainerImpl.startInitialization(CDIContainerImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.cdi.liberty.CDIRuntimeImpl.applicationStarting(CDIRuntimeImpl.java:487)
    at com.ibm.ws.container.service.state.internal.ApplicationStateManager.fireStarting(ApplicationStateManager.java:53)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.ibm.ws.cdi.proxy.ProxyServicesImpl.defineClass(ProxyServicesImpl.java:150)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyFactory.toClass(ProxyFactory.java:940)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyFactory.createProxyClass(ProxyFactory.java:495)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyFactory.getProxyClass(ProxyFactory.java:401)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @69d7d0b0
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:199)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:193)
    at com.ibm.ws.cdi.proxy.ProxyServicesImpl$ClassLoaderMethods$1.run(ProxyServicesImpl.java:73)
    at com.ibm.ws.cdi.proxy.ProxyServicesImpl$ClassLoaderMethods$1.run(ProxyServicesImpl.java:61)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:569)
    at com.ibm.ws.cdi.proxy.ProxyServicesImpl$ClassLoaderMethods.<clinit>(ProxyServicesImpl.java:61)
    ... 28 more


Answering my own question :
I just had to add a jvm.options file with the following content:
--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED


How did you start your server?  That --add-opens should already be added to the JVM arguments when using server start command.

Well, that's strange because I start my server using command server start myServer. That server was created using command server create my Server. My application is deployed in dropins. I plan to move it to apps, after the rest of the configuration satisfies me.
Not sure if that's relevant, I edited my post to include the complete server.xml file, just in case

This used to be a more common problem when the Java executable came from a path that was a symbolic link like when it is found in the /usr/bin or /bin directory. We did several changes over the last year to make that work by following the symbolic links to get to the actual path that Java is at in order to determine if it has a particular directory to tell us that the Java version is Java 11+. From that we end up adding to the Java arguments the --add-opens and --add-exports arguments needed by the liberty runtime. I would try setting JAVA_HOME to the Java path since you're using 24.0.0.11

Good catch! My java installation is actually on a weird path (not in /usr), so any attempt to determine the java version using its path would surely fail. I am currently developping my application, and don't think I can expect the path to java to be neat when it is used in the real world. So I guess I am stuck with the --add-opens options. Would it not be simpler to just add an option to specify the java version to use? If you write an answer to my question I will accept it.

We did a lot of work to make this work even with things being in weird paths.  So I would still like to understand your scenario to determine if there is something that was missed with the way that we do things.  I don't expect that your Java has to be in the /usr directory at all.  The main issue we run into is with symbolic links.  We updated to follow symbolic links so that is why I am concerned about why it isn't working for you.

I am testing my application with different JDK versions on the same machine. My application is installed in several subfolders. I need the default java version (in the Path) to be different depending on the "current" environment. I added a script called ~/bin/java to my $PATH that acts as a proxy between the caller and the actual java binary. The script determines the java version to use based on the result of the pwd command and calls it.
I know this trick is awful, but it mostly works and it is all I could find to solve my problem.
Why not just call java -version?

Calling java -version adds a second java call to the start of every server which increases start time.  The script currently just looks to see if $JAVA_HOME/jmods exists.  We calculate the JAVA_HOME if it isn't set in the current environment.  My guess is possibly the ~/bin/ is messing up our calculation to determine where JAVA_HOME is.
